# Heading style with pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a heading for a web page that is supposed to look like this

[image]

And i'd like to use css to style it. One way is to use pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` with `h3` tag, and use `content:url(...image.png);`, but Is it possible to create something like this using only css, and not using images?

I could create on of those using `:before` and `:after`, by specifying borders, width and height, and absolutely positioning them, but that way I couldn't create the other side. Are there some line parameters in css to help me create it?

Here's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L42LL/) of what I have right now.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>CONTACT US</h3>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    position:relative;
    left:100px;    
}

h3{
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #222222;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 48px;
    margin-bottom: 26px;
    position: relative;
}

h3:before{
    content:"";
    border-right: 1px solid #e65941;
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    left:-50px;
    bottom:5px;
}

h3:after{
    content:"";
    border-left: 1px solid #e65941;
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right:-50px;
    bottom:5px;
}
```

Comment: Ok, why the down vote the second I wrote the question? :\

Comment: if you want it done in only css - what effort have you made to accomplish that?

Comment: @DanielA.White, at least there's some attempt at figuring it out? Shows at least minimal effort in my opinion.

Comment: I'll post jsfiddle in a moment. I'm at work atm and I'm trying to figure this out...

Comment: Not exactly what you want but may send you down the right track: http://cyberliving.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/how-to-draw-lines-using-css.html

Comment: Yeah, that would require of me addition of extra divs, and since I'm editing wordpress templates, that's kinda not practical.

Comment: Have you considered unicode characters [right tack](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22a2/index.htm) and [left tack](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22a3/index.htm)?

Comment: This would work! Thank you :) EDIT: I can't seem to use it. I put `content:\&#8866`; in my pseudo elements but nothing...

Comment: For uniform background and one-line heading, you can also use something like http://jsfiddle.net/h46M7/

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn this worked perfectly! Thank you. Feel free to put it as an answer so that I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we are:

1. Create the left and right borders with the `h3` itself.
2. Adjust `bottom` on `:before` and `:after` to get the exact result you want.

[Have a jsBin!](http://jsbin.com/zipup/3/edit) - updated the link, jsfiddle is crashing on me so I have uploaded to jsBin

I have done a bit of a tidy up, and have removed the container as the `h3` styling is self-contained.

CSS

```
h3 {
    position:relative;
    font-family:Lato;
    font-weight:300;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#222;
    font-size:40px;
    margin:30px;
    border-left:solid 1px #e65941;
    border-right:solid 1px #e65941;
    padding:0 10px;
}
h3:before,h3:after {
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    border-bottom:1px solid #e65941;
    width:30px;
    bottom:23px
}
h3:before {
    left:-30px
}
h3:after {
    right:-30px
}
```

Comment: Jep this works as well, IlyaStreltsyn pointed it out first. If he doesn't post answer, I'll post yours as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, no worries - couldn't load their fiddle to check :)

Comment: Actually, your works better, because I don't need background, which is kinda problematic it seems. Thank you!!